# What are the common causes of excess protein (1 g) in the urine for kidney donors?

Tags: lifestyle, kidney, urine, renal, organ-donation

I am looking for common causes in diet or lifestyle or other conditions such as hypertension, rather than malfunction in the active (single) kidney.

Apart from medical management, what are some changes in diet or lifestyle that can be adopted to minimize the worsening, or to reduce excess protein output in the urine?